# finding number of words present in the string in java using recursion

Tags: java, recursion, methods

A class words defines a recursive function to perform string related operations. The class details
are given below:

```
Class name : words
Data members/instance variables
 text : to store string.
 w : integer variable to store total words.
Member functions/methods
 words( ) : constructor to store blank to string and 0 to integer data.
 void Accept( ) : to read a sentence in text. Note that the sentence may contain more
 than one blank space between words.
 int FindWords(int) : to count total number of words present in text using Recursive
 Technique and store in ‘w’ and return.
 void Result( ) : to display the original string. Print total number of words stored in
 ‘w’ by invoking the recursive function.
```

I tried this code

```
public static int CountWords(String str) {
    int c = 0;
    int i = str.indexOf(" ");
    if (str.isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    }else 
        if (i == str.indexOf(" ")) {
      return c++;
   }
  //str.substring(0,str.indexOf(" ")-1);
    c++;
    return c + CountWords(str.substring(i + 1));
}
```

but i need to return an integer value and i am confused with that..

Comment: This *does* "return an integer value".

Comment: Your "class details" do not explain what `CountWords` is supposed to do.

Comment: I know a different method of doing this task but i need an "int" parameter in the function FindWords()

Comment: According to the question, the parameter has to be an integer and not string

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the last return statement is inaccessible. Reason: you have put an if-else block and have put return in both the cases. So the function actually gets returned from the if-else block itself (within else, the condition of if is always true since you assigned the very value i.e. str.indexOf(" ")).

I have written down the code according to the question you gave above...

```
public int findWords(int i){
    if(i > text.lastIndexOf(" "))
        return 1;
    i = text.substring(i).indexOf(" ") + i;
    if(i < 0)
        return 1;
    if(text.substring(i).equals(null))
        return 0;
    return( findWords(i+1) + 1);
}
```

Hope you find it well working.

Answer (score 0):

Your function already is returning a integer, it just happens to always be 0.
This is due to

```
else if (i == str.indexOf(" ")) {
  return c++;
}
```

Always being true and c++ only updating after the return statement was passed.
This happens because you already set i to be the indexOf(" ") and due to the implementation of incrementation using int++. Also, keep in mind hat you need to increase the number of words by 2 here, since you're ending the function between two words.

Therefore, use this instead:

```
else if (i == str.lastIndexOf(" ")) {
  return c+2;
}
```

You should see that now the function is returning the correct amount of words.

Comment: According to the question, he doesn't have to take a string parameter input. It needs to be int

Comment: Where does it say that? The last line reads "but i need to **return** an integer value and i am confused with that.."
Unless of course, FindWords and CountWords are meant to be the same function

Comment: Obviously CountWords and FindWords seem to mean the same thing...